# Pointer to struct, trying to refer to its data members - C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have this code:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char* data;
    struct node next;
} node;

typedef struct linkedList
{
    node head;
    int size;
} linkedList;

typedef struct _MyLinkedList *MyLinkedListP
{
    struct linkedList* listp;
};

MyLinkedListP createList()
{
    linkedList *list = (linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
    (*list).head = NULL;
    (*list).size = 0;
    MyLinkedListP listP = list;
    return listP;
}
```

I am trying to build a function:

```
MyLinkedListP cloneList(MyLinkedListP l)
```

`l` is a pointer to a `linkedList`, I am trying to get its members (size and first node), in order to complete the function. But I just do not understand how to do it under this build.
I also want to ask regarding my build of struct `MyLinkedListP`. My goal was to create a type that is a pointer to a `linkedList`, is the way I did it good practice?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Do not use identifiers starting with underscore then a capital letter; they are reserved for the implementation.  Do not cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: `struct node next;` --> `struct node *next;` and `node head;` --> `node *head;` Don't you get compiler warnings?

Comment: The arrow `->` operator was invented so that you wouldn't have to use `(*ptr).member` notation.  It also nests more cleanly: `ptr->memberptr->member` vs `(*(*ptr).memberptr).member` (and if there's a mistake in the nested dotted notation, it only reinforces the easier readability of the arrow notation).

Comment: Incdidentally, the lines `typedef struct _MyLinkedList *MyLinkedListP
{
    struct linkedList* listp;
};` don't compile, do they?  You could place a semicolon after the P and what goes before would be clean.  You would have to provide a `struct DoHickey` line before the body of the structure definition, though (for some value of `DoHickey`) before the second part of that fragment could compile.

Comment: _l is a pointer to a linkedList_  - no. `l` has a member `listp`, a pointer to a linkedList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this won't work:

```
typedef struct node
{
  char* data;
  struct node next;
} node;
```

A `struct` type may not contain a member that's an instance of itself<sup>1</sup>;  this should be written as

```
typedef struct node
{
  char* data;
  struct node *next;  // next is a *pointer* to struct node
} node;
```

Secondly, while the following isn't a *problem* like the above, this is not good practice:

```
typedef struct _MyLinkedList *MyLinkedListP
```

Identifiers with leading underscores are reserved for the implementation; you should not create any type or object names with leading underscores.  Just use

```
typedef struct MyLinkedList *MyLinkedListP
```

instead<sup>2</sup>.

Third, lose the cast in

```
linkedList *list = (linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(linkedList));
```

It's not necessary (since C89), it clutters up the call, and it creates maintenance headaches.  That can be made much simpler as follows:

```
linkedList *list = malloc( sizeof *list );
```

Fourth, note that you can write

```
(*list).head = NULL;
(*list).size = 0;
```

as

```
list->head = NULL;
list->size = 0;
```

`a->b` is shorthand for `(*a).b`, and makes things a little easier to read.

Finally,

```
MyLinkedListP listP = list;
```

is attempting to assing a value of type `struct linkedList *` to an object of type `struct MyLinkedList *`, and they aren't compatible.  Based on the code you've shared, it *looks* like you meant to do something more like

```
struct MyLinkedList myList;
list.listp = list;
```

or

```
struct MyLinkedList myList = {list};
```

or even

```
MyLinkedListP listP = malloc( sizeof *listP ); // leaky abstraction from hiding
                                               // pointer behind typedef

listP->listp = list;
```

I suggest you take a step back and try to simplify what you're doing - you've added a bit of unnecessary complexity with your types.

---

1. First of all, the `struct node` type isn't *complete* until the closing `}` of the struct definition, and you can't declare an *instance* of an incomplete type; you can, however, declare a *pointer* to an incomplete type.  Secondly, the size to store an instance of `struct node` would have to be infinite, since the instance contains an instance of itself, which contains an instance of itself, which contains an instance of itself, etc.

   A quick rant - as a rule, you should not hide pointers behind typedefs.  If the programmer has to ever be aware that they are dealing with a pointer (for example, if they need to access members of the struct type), then make that explicit in the declaration of the pointer object (look at the `FILE` type in stdio.h as an example - even though you only ever deal with *pointers* to `FILE`s, that pointer is not part of the `FILE` typedef).

Comment: You guys are so awesome, thank you very much. especially John, that is a great answer

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `struct node` won't compile, because it is trying to contain itself in its definition. Instead, use indirection via a pointer.

```
typedef struct node
{
    char* data;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

The definition of `struct _MyLinkedList` is incorrect, since the body has to follow the tag. Mirror your syntax for `struct node` and place the alias after the struct declaration.

```
typedef struct _MyLinkedList
{
    struct linkedList* listp;
} *MyLinkedListP;
```

Since the `head` member of `struct linkedList` is not a pointer variable, the assignment will not compile. If you meant for the assignment to succeed, then change the definition of `struct linkedList` accordingly.

```
typedef struct linkedList
{
    node *head;
    int size;
} linkedList;
```

Your are assigning a `struct linkedList *` to a `struct _MyLinkedList *`, but they are not compatible. Since your function wants to return a `struct _MyLinkedList *`, you should properly allocate one to be returned.

```
MyLinkedListP listP = malloc(sizeof(*listP));
listP->listp = list;
return listP;
```

With all the changes together, and fixing up some stylistic issues:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char* data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct linkedList
{
    node *head;
    int size;
} linkedList;

typedef struct _MyLinkedList
{
    struct linkedList* listp;
} *MyLinkedListP;

MyLinkedListP createList()
{
    linkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->head = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    MyLinkedListP listP = malloc(sizeof(*listP));
    listP->listp = list;
    return listP;
}
```